# How do i add MongoDBAdapter to next js

Tags: mongodb, next.js, next-auth

When i import the adapter to my nextauth page, it makes the login with google to redirect to

```
http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin?error=OAuthAccountNotLinked
```

and status says unauthenticated, but without adding the adapter both login with google and credentials works just fine, mi expecting after login the code to create a session in the database but all I'm getting is this unexpected behaviour

```
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import clientPromise from "../../../libs/mongoConnect";
import { MongoDBAdapter } from "@auth/mongodb-adapter";

const handler = NextAuth({
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  //adapter:MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise),
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
            }),
        CredentialsProvider({
            name: 'Credentials',
            id: 'credentials',
            credentials: {
              username: { label: "Email", type: "email", placeholder: "test@example.com" },
              password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
            },
            async authorize(credentials, req) {
              const email = credentials?.email;
              const password = credentials?.password;

              mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL);
              const user = await User.findOne({email});
              const passwordOk = user && bcrypt .compareSync(password, user.password);

             if (passwordOk) {
              return user;
             }
              return null
            }
          })
    ],
});
```